# Parse error when loading WKT Multipolygons into postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to add a .csv table with Multipolygons in WKT into a postgresql table. Im using the import function and all .csv columns match the existing ones.
However I always geht this error:

```
FEHLER:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "..." <-- parse error at position 35024 within geometry
CONTEXT:  COPY einzugsgebiete, Zeile 22, Spalte geometrie: »MULTIPOLYGON (((416658.4569 5657578.43989841,416669.8893 5657574.44109841,416672.0125 5657579.251398...«
```

I should specify that the polygons are very detailed with a lot of points in between and if possible I want to keep them like that.

I tried to rearrange the data but the Error always appears at position 35024

Comment: so what is at position 35024? If your input really contains `...` then you need to fix the input

Comment: Typically this is the result of bad data for the polygon definition. A common error being the ending point in the definition does not correspond to the beginning point. These must be the same (within a small tolerance - the *error of closure*).  Without seeing the complete definition I cannot be sure; you need each check the polygon definition for this. The '...' in the error message is just Postgres indicating there is more data but not presented due to size, it presents just enough for you to identify the incorrect record.